# MYSQL LIKE in same column several times

Tags: php, mysql

I have filter with 3 dropdown lists, each list contains same criteria (operator, service, SIM card). When these dropdown lists contain diferent search categories, search function is working fine, but if categories is the same in 2 or 3 dropdown lists, filter doesnt work correctly. Because of incorrect SQL query:

`"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'] . " AND operator like %tele% AND operator like %bite%"`

should be

`"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'] . " AND operator like %tele% OR operator like %bite%"`

This is my php code for filter:

```
 $this->_sql['where'].= $this->reg['post']['flt_find_1'] ? " AND ".$this->reg['post']['flt_field_1']." like '%".$this->reg['post']['flt_find_1']."%' " : "";      
 $this->_sql['where'].= $this->reg['post']['flt_find_2'] ? " AND ".$this->reg['post']['flt_field_2']." like '%".$this->reg['post']['flt_find_2']."%' " : "";  
 $this->_sql['where'].= $this->reg['post']['flt_find_3'] ? " AND ".$this->reg['post']['flt_field_3']." like '%".$this->reg['post']['flt_find_3']."%' " : "";
```

How to check if all categories in the filter are different, then use `AND` for each, but then categories are the same, to use `OR` (or maybe there is other way to solve that).

Thanks.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . $_GET . " AND operator like %tele% OR operator like %bite%"` - Why are you concatenating a string and an array?

Comment: @Sann I made a mistake, I have edited my question.

Comment: You are not sanitizing. stop right there and rethink what you are doing.

Comment: @Hiroto I know, I just wrote that for this question, this not what I am asking for, thanks.

Comment: Please show your html code too.

Comment: @deju88 You don't deliberately stick security exploits in SO questions. Use your real code (and I assume this is it regardless) if you don’t want people to mention it. You *never* think about security second.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code is vulnerable to sql-injections, so check the get parameter;
2. If I understand you correctly, try it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '".($_GET['id']*1)."' AND ( operator LIKE '%tele%' AND operator LIKE '%bite%' )";
```

Comment: yes that part I know and it is working, the problem is I dont know how to check that in PHP part.

Comment: Can you explain more specific, what exactly you don't understand? Because the query already returns all needed data.

Comment: In my original post is a part of PHP code where I need to check when to use `OR` and when to use `AND`. Because now as you can see, my filter always use AND for each filter category. Sorry for my english.